# Authenticating function to function calls for firebase functions on server side

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

We are using firebase cloud functions in our application. We have 2 firebase functions: 1. A regular firebase cloud function that runs at regular intervals, 2. A firebase http function that is invoked by function #1 and can also be invoked from outside the application environment (in future). We have a use case where we have #1 firebase cloud function processes thousands of user records and performs some specific operations by invoking the #2 firebase http function. Our requirement now is to authenticate the invocation of the firebase http function. Both the firebase functions are in the same service account.

Following the steps in the documentation : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_function_to_function_calls we tried to create an Id token in the calling function and included the ID token in an Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN header in the request to the http function.

Our code to obtain the id token. We tried using the firebase receiving function url, our firebase project url

```
const { URL } = require('url')
const targetAudience = new URL(url)
const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience)
const idToken = await client.request({ url })
```

Our code to verify the token

```
 const tokenId = request.get('Authorization').split('Bearer ')[1]
 const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(tokenId)
```

We get back an idToken correctly, but when that token is verified, we always get this error :

> Error while verifying Firebase ID token: { Error: Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "`<firebase-project-name>`" but got "https://`<cloud-function-endpoint>`". Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.

const targetAudience = new URL(url) - for the target audience we tried the firebase function URL of the http function, the name of the project, adding https to the name of the project, but we always keep getting the same error Firebase ID token has an incorrect "aud" claim

Any pointers on what we could we doing wrong? Has anyone tried to authenticate invocation to one cloud function when the calling function is another cloud function in the same service account.

Answer (score 0):

try to generate the idToken this way

```
const serviceAccountEmail = '...';
const generateIdToken = async () => {
    const tokens = await admin.options.credential?.getAccessToken();
    const projectId = 
    const res = await fetch(`https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/${serviceAccountEmail}:generateIdToken`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${tokens?.access_token}`,
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            delegates: [
            ],
            audience: projectId,
            includeEmail: true
        }),
    });
    return res.json();
}
```

## Roles needed on the service account

- Service Account Token Creator
- Service Account User

## Google APIs enable on the project

- IAM Service Account Credentials API

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above API to get the id token, however I get back an error : Error: Request failed with status code 403, which means the access if forbidden. When I read the documentation for this API: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateIdToken, they ask us to include the service account name in the delegates array, I passed in an empty delegates array, should I try adding the service account ?

Comment: When I checked the role for the service account that I used, it's an "Owner" role so that should have the Service Account Token Creator and Service Account User role correct?

Comment: how are initializing the admin? with the service account that comes from default on cloud function? the engine one? or you are using another service account?

Comment: Initializing it with the same service account with the same project id

Comment: admin.auth to create custom token and other admin Api seem to work fine

Comment: On this page https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateIdToken, I could try out the rest api to see if I get a result I passed in the same service account details and I got a 403 error via the rest api on this page too.

Answer (score -1):

it seems the admin.auth().verifyToken is expecting the audience to be the projectId instead of the url of the function endpoint.

normally what I do when I want a function to be private(only invoke from other functions) I make it "require authentication(Manage authorized users with Cloud IAM.)" then I don't even have to verify the id token in my implementation.

Comment: Project id is not a valid URL. So that wouldn't work. Please elaborate on the second part of your answer.

Comment: @VarunGupta did you tested it. audience does not have to be an URL, in fact the idToken you send to the server when an user is authenticated does not have url audience, they have the project id

Comment: Yes, we tested that. We got the following error: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: <firebase-project-name>`

Comment: it seems like auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience) which a firebase implementation checks for for the audience to be an URL but in really the rest API doesn't require that. Look here https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateIdToken I will elaborate more about how I did it in the pass

Comment: As per your suggestion, we have set the firebase function to require authentication so that we don't have to use the verify id token in the implementation. I am able to get the id token as per the instructions in this URL : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_function_to_function_calls . I am then passing the id token as part of the authentication header and invoking the firebase HTTP function this way:

Comment: axios(url, {
                  method: 'post',
                  url: Constants.VERIFY_RECEIPT_URL_PRODUCTION,
                  headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    accept: 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                  },
                  data: {
                    uid: uid,
                    refreshToken: refreshToken,
                    timeMax: timeMax,
                  },
                })

Comment: However what I see is that request body is null, the request seems to have authenticated successfully because it's executing the function, printing logs, however the request body is being sent as empty. When I did not send a header as part of the post request, the request body was being read correctly. Any idea where we could be wrong and if firebase functions expect a different parameter when we include a header?

Comment: It all worked out finally, turned out that I could specify the data as part of the OAuth client.request API itself, the problem was I thought my axios post was triggering the HTTP function, but the call const idToken = await client.request({ url }) was actually invoking the HTTP function, all I had to do was pass data parameter to this request and it all worked. I thought client.request returns an id token but it actually returns the result of the firebase function call.