# Function to Function call - how to verify incoming credential

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm building functions as independent microservices and need to do a function to function http call.

I've found this to be straightforward by simply making a call to the receiving function url. However, given that the receiving function validates incoming credentials from other calls (currently just authenticated firebase users), I need to develop additional validation so existing validation does reject the call. This is necessary given that the new incoming function call has no user credentials.

What I think is true is that the incoming function call will be under the principal account `firebase-adminsdk-****....` with the role of `Cloud Functions Admin`.

How do I know for sure? How can validate these permissions in my application code? E.g. if principal is `firebase-adminsdk-****....` or a firebase user, allow.

I need to develop the appropriate validation so my existing validation does not reject the call from the admin-sdk principal, given that it has no incoming user credentials.

Comment: Do you need the user identity to perform validation? Or do you need more?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I don't know what you mean. This will be a function to function call - there will be no user identity.

Comment: Hi @skwny, Could you please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496535/authenticating-function-to-function-calls-for-firebase-functions-on-server-side) and see if it helps.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB that was actually very helpful, thank you.